# Does Javonet support mono (out of the box) and therefore runs on Mac and Linux?

Tags: javonet

Does Javonet support mono (out of the box) and therefore runs on Mac and Linux? (JNBridge claims to support it; j4net does not officially support it, though some posts claim it does work under certain scenarios.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javonet does not support Linux or Mac in current release, but we do have very advanced progress in that field and we plan to provide it in near term.

Comment: Great! Any clues what "near term" might mean (even if it's just beta version?) (That is, are we talking a couple weeks, couple months, or end of year?)

Comment: We cannot provide any binding declaration but we should look into something around couple of months.